# Waiting for the result from callback before reducing

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'd like to know if I'm able to make this work with `setTimeout`.
The function `together` has to take the `funcs` which is a list of async functions and a `pred` and the `n`.
Each of function has to call the `callback` which has to return either a value or an error.
It is working if I remove `setTimeout` and leave only `return cb(...)`, but I'd like to `setTimeout` before I call the `callback` in each of the function.
The `together` has to return an Array of results which were accepted by `pred`, e.g. if `pred > 10`, the `results` contain only values that are greater than 10.

My code:

```
function fun1(value,cb) {
    if ((value * 100) > 400)  {
        return setTimeout(() => cb(null, value*100), 2000)
    }
    else {
      return cb(new Error("error"))
    }
}
function fun2(value,cb) {
    if ((value * 20) > 50)  {
        return setTimeout(() => cb(null, value*20), 2000)
    }
    else {
      return cb(new Error("error"))
    }
}

function fun3(value,cb) {
    if ((value -30 ) > 0)  {
      return setTimeout(() => cb(null, value-30), 2000)
    }
    else {
      return cb(new Error("error"))
    }
}
function callback(err, wyn) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    else {
        return wyn
    }


}
//console.log(fun1(1000,callback))

const together = (funcs, pred) => (n) => {
    let results = []
    funcs.reduce((prev,curr) => {
        if (curr(n,callback) > pred) {
            results.push(curr(n,callback))
        }

    }, 0)
    return results
};

console.log(together([fun1,fun2,fun3], 5)(10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Promises` and `Promises.all` to get the values of these promises. You can either use `then/catch` or `async/await`.

```
function fun1(value,cb) {
   return new Promise ((res, rej) => {
      if ((value * 100) > 400)  {
        return  setTimeout(() => res(cb(null, value*100)), 2000);
    }
    else {
      rej(cb(new Error("error")));
    }
   })
   
}
function fun2(value,cb) {
    return new Promise ((res, rej) => {
      if ((value * 20) > 50)  {
        setTimeout(() => res(cb(null, value*20)), 2000);
    }
    else {
      rej(cb(new Error("error")))
    }
   })
   
}

function fun3(value,cb) {
   return new Promise ((res, rej) => {
      if ((value -30 ) > 0)  {
      setTimeout(() => res(cb(null, value-30)), 2000)
    }
    else {
      rej(cb(new Error("error")));
    }
   })
    
}
function callback(err, wyn) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    else {
        return wyn
    }


}
//console.log(fun1(1000,callback))

const together = (funcs, pred) => (n) => {
    let results = []
    funcs.forEach((func) => {
            results.push(curr(n,callback))
       
    })
    // if any of your callback returns rejection it will not give values
    Promise.all(results).then(values => { 
     //values will be an array
    console.log(values[0])
   }).catch(console.log);
};

console.log(together([fun1,fun2,fun3], 5)(10))
```

Instead of using reduce, use `forEach` or `for` loops, check when to use [reduce](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reduce-f47a7da511a9/) method.

Comment: If that works for you, you can accept the answer it will award points to both. Thanks!

Comment: Btw. why can't I use reduce here? What if I wanted to use reduce?

Comment: What could I do to make in this `forEach` if (func(n,callback) > pred)? it doesn't work

Comment: As you cb are async in nature ofcourse. You can make a synchronous call as your subsequent  requests are based on cb values and for loops are always sync in nature.

Comment: what about filtering inside the `Promise.all` the results? I don't excatly know what you mean by making a synchronus call.

Comment: I thought you want your methods to be called one after the other. Definitely you can add any condition in it.

Comment: according to what you thought - they are going one after the the other, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, they are going, but promise.all will be only resolved if all the promises resolved. they don't wait for the others to resolve its previous promises.

Comment: so it's not possible to take them into results if at least one of the promise will give the error?

Comment: Yes, you might need to handle that with wrapper and generated custom error message. Also, if you want to run the function sequentially you need to use generator functions.